# surfaceview, activity, startactivityforresult, dialog in activity

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

Im working on a little game and having some issues.

There is the Menu

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.bStartGame:

        Intent a = new Intent(Menu.this, Action.class);
        startActivityForResult(a, 1);

        break; }
```

then the activity which starts a surfaceview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
}
```

and then the the surfaceView with the game mechanics.

Most of my code is in this view.

Now I have the problem to find a good solution for the gameoverscreen.

If I start a new activity inside the surfaceview, it works - but i dont get the result() which is the score achieved during a session.

So now I wanted to ask you guys how to solve this issue.

I thought of a way, but dont know how to implement it.
It would be to pass the highscore from the surfaceview to the activity and set it as a result(which the menu activity gets back) there.
And start an xml file via dialog, which would be the gameoverscreen and as soon as the player touches the back button he gets back to the menu where he can see his achieved score.

Can you please tell me how to code this?

Kind regards
Denis

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to solve this:

-use startActivityForResult and then send it back from your new activity, catching it in the old activity using onActivityResult (check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

-do what i did (the lazy, hacky way :): start the new activity with startActivity() and add the highscore as extra data added to the intent. In your new activity, use getIntent().getInt (ow whatever) to get the sent score data and do with it what you will. Then close that activity and you'll return to the previous one holding your surfaceview.

NOW THE TRICK: before you start your new activity with it's score added to the intent, just run the same score calculation in your surfaceview's activity as you would in your new activity! That way, when you return to your surfaceview's activity, you will still have the correct, new score (if stored/onresume'd correctly; don't forget to add it to your save/restore state and/oror the surfaceview's private variables)!

The only downside is that you'll have two location you have to update your scoring mechanics at. And it's not good programming. But it works and it's easy.

Comment: Running the same calculation isn't necessary bad style, but code duplication is! Find another source organization...